# Python output gets changed when using f.read and f.readline after writing in r+ mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, fopen, fwrite, fclose

I am using f.readline() and f.read() but both are generating different files in respect to pointer.
One is starting from 0 and appending at last and the other replaces the text with

This is the code with read

```
f = open('k.txt', 'w')

f.write('I love python very much\n')

f.write('Because of its vast community support\n')

f.write('and huge inbuilt libs\n')

f.close()


f = open('k.txt', 'r+')

f.write('I love coding at school but its covid now\n')

#print(f.tell())

print(f.read())

f.close()
```

This is the second code with readline

```
f = open('k.txt', 'w')

f.write('I love python very much\n')

f.write('Because of its vast community support\n')

f.write('and huge inbuilt libs\n')

f.close()


f = open('k.txt', 'r+')

f.write('I love coding at school but its covid now\n')

#print(f.tell())

print(f.readline())

f.close()
```

Can you tell why the pointer is behaving like that in both cases